# jquery sliders and toastr conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I was using 3 different type of sliders in my ASP.Net site (i.e. [***MenuCool***](http://www.menucool.com/slider/javascript-image-slider-demo1),[***jQuery Accordian***](http://www.madeincima.it/download/samples/jquery/easyAccordion/) and [***Slider***](http://365psd.com/day/225/)). What I done recently is that i included a jquery [**toastr**](http://codeseven.github.com/toastr/) to show some messages. which also has `jQuery.min` referenced.

When the page loaded it is all good. But when the toastr message is shown all 3 sliders are not working. I thinks the problem is with the conflict in `jquery.min` files.

I tried to commenting references one by one. but the problem persists.
Is their a single reference or version that works with all.
**Note:** i also installed toastr from Nuget as described [***here***](http://nuget.org/packages/toastr).
Currently i have those references

- http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js
- http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js
- 

and those files in script folder

[image]

**Is Their a single jQuery file or reference that work with all those sliders?**

Answer (score 0):

Finally after 3 days searching on `jquery` and `javascript` i found the issue.

The problem was with the `update panel`. When the `button` event is fired in `update panel` all my `sliders` are not working so i put my button in `update panel` and slider outside the panel. This fixes all.